# How to sum all the values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, sum

Let's say I have a dictionary in which the keys map to integers like:

```
d = {'key1': 1,'key2': 14,'key3': 47}
```

Is there a syntactically minimalistic way to return the sum of the values in `d`—i.e. `62` in this case?

Comment: Just for fun: implement `sum` yourself in terms of [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) -- `reduce` is a more general form (e.g. `sum`, `min` and `max` can all be written in terms of `reduce`) and can solve other problems (e.g. `product`) easily.

Comment: What about Guido's saying -- I think I remember this correctly -- that reduce is going away? I'm with you. Why remove it from the language?

Answer (score 727, accepted):

As you'd expect:

```
sum(d.values())
```

Comment: Well,`Python 2.7.12` also works well with `sum(d.values())`

Comment: @LancelotHolmes Yes, but that builds a list in memory, and can thus be slower/closer to resource limits for large dictionaries. Thus, this answer says "you *may* want to use" instead of "you *must* use" when discussing Python 2.

Comment: Nice! I sought it up just because I knew there would be something like that. Not that it takes  too much work to write a dead silly for loop though ;)

Comment: I don't know if you love python, if you love python 3, or if really are referring to a python 2

Comment: @LucasVazquez This referred to Python 2 (or 1). I removed it since it's irrelevant nowadays – even if you write new code in Python2, you can use `d.values()`.

Answer (score 72):

In Python 2 you can avoid making a temporary copy of all the values by using the `itervalues()` dictionary method, which returns an iterator of the dictionary's keys:

```
sum(d.itervalues())
```

In Python 3 you can just use `d.values()` because that method was changed to do that (and `itervalues()` was removed since it was no longer needed).

To make it easier to write version independent code which always iterates over the values of the dictionary's keys, a utility function can be helpful:

```
import sys

def itervalues(d):
    return iter(getattr(d, ('itervalues', 'values')[sys.version_info[0]>2])())

sum(itervalues(d))
```

This is essentially what Benjamin Peterson's [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/) module does.

Comment: yup, though this does not apply for python 3.

Answer (score 20):

Sure there is. Here is a way to sum the values of a dictionary.

```
>>> d = {'key1':1,'key2':14,'key3':47}
>>> sum(d.values())
62
```

Answer (score 9):

```
d = {'key1': 1,'key2': 14,'key3': 47}
sum1 = sum(d[item] for item in d)
print(sum1)
```

you can do it using the for loop

Answer (score 8):

`sum(d.values())`

- "d" -> Your dictionary Variable

Answer (score 5):

I feel `sum(d.values())` is the most efficient way to get the sum.

You can also try the reduce function to calculate the sum along with a lambda expression:

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,d.values())
```

Answer (score 5):

USE sum() TO SUM THE VALUES IN A DICTIONARY.

Call dict.values() to return the values of a dictionary dict.
Use sum(values) to return the sum of the values from the previous step.

```
d = {'key1':1,'key2':14,'key3':47}
values = d.values()
#Return values of a dictionary    
total = sum(values)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 3):

phihag's answer (and similar ones) won't work in python3.

**For python 3:**

```
d = {'key1': 1,'key2': 14,'key3': 47}
sum(list(d.values()))
```

---

Update! 
There are complains that it doesn't work! I just attach a screenshot from my terminal. Could be some mismatch in versions etc.

[image]

Comment: Same issue exist even if we try this way

Comment: it just works fine for me! I updated my answer with a screenshot (cannot do it here); it might have something to do with versions...

Answer (score 0):

You could consider 'for loop' for this:

```
  d = {'data': 100, 'data2': 200, 'data3': 500}
  total = 0
  for i in d.values():
        total += i
```

total = 800

Comment: Or just `sum(d.values())`, since `.values()` returns a `List`.

Comment: yeah that is another way as well.

Answer (score 0):

simplest/silliest solution:

https://trinket.io/python/a8a1f25353

```
d = {'key1': 1,'key2': 14,'key3': 47}
s = 0
for k in d:
    s += d[k]

print(s)
```

or if you want it fancier:

https://trinket.io/python/5fcd379536

```
import functools

d = {'key1': 1,'key2': 14,'key3': 47}
s = functools.reduce(lambda acc,k: acc+d[k], d, 0)

print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a generator of all the values in the dictionary, then cast it to a list and use the sum() function to get the sum of all the values.

Example:

```py
c={"a":123,"b":4,"d":4,"c":-1001,"x":2002,"y":1001}

sum(list(c.values()))
```

Comment: How is this an answer, if it does not work. Look more like a comment to other answers.

Comment: looks like working code to me and solves OP's problem and infact should have been the selected answer.