# Adding Multiple Values with Upper Limit on Sum of All Values

Tags: python

I'm trying to think of some way to implement this concept (in Python, but I can translate so that's not an issue) but have no idea where to begin:

this is the setup:

```
#"collection"        "oNum"                 "object"
object_collection = [[o01, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o02, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o03, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o04, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o05, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o06, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o07, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o08, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o09, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o10, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o11, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o12, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o13, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o14, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o15, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o16, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o17, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o18, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o19, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o20, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o21, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o22, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o23, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]],
                     [o24, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]]]
```

This may be better outlined as a dictionary, I'm aware, so that's not a limitation.

Parameters of the problem are: 
1. Need to Sum the values of the "objects" where 
----> All "objects" will be random integers between the values of 0 and 15 
----> All "objects'" combined total cannot exceed 100 (but they can be less than 100)

for example:

```
object_collection = [[o01, [11]], # 0 + 11 = 11
                     [o02, [2]], # 11 + 2 = 13
                     [o03, [1]], # 13 + 1 = 14
                     [o04, [6]], # 14 + 6 = 20
                     [o05, [5]], # 20 + 5 = 25
                     [o06, [4]], # 25 + 4 = 29
                     [o07, [3]], # 29 + 3 = 32
                     [o08, [2]], # 32 + 2 = 34
                     [o09, [1]], #... 
#                    X + Y <= 100
#... you get the point
```

The the total value will exceed 100 if all 24 values are set to the maximum, but the basis of the question is centered around identifying correlations between the ***ratios*** rather than the individual raw data points. Technically, each "object" has a maximum of 100, but setting one object's value to 100 leaves 0 for any other object.

I've tried a few things already, but any help you may have would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code you tried and error you are facing?

Comment: Actually, it's similar to the question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880960/sum-of-all-values-in-a-python-dict but the difference is that I have a range of values rather than a single integer as well as my question has an upper bound of 100 for the sum of all the "object" variables (ranges).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin