# How to sum number of total individual items in a list?

Tags: python, list

I've been looking with no success for a way to sum the total number of items in a list. Using ATBS beginner python book. My code is as follows:

```
import pprint 
items = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12} 

print('Inventory:')

for item, inven_count in items.items():
    item_total = ???
    print(str(inven_count) + ' ' + item)

print('Total number of items: ' + str(item_total))
```

The item_total line is what I'm unsure of. I know that the answer I want is 62, but I've been unable to think of the right way to word my code to reach that answer. Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you aware of the ``+=`` operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum all the values in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880960/how-to-sum-all-the-values-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Sushanth No need to manually discard the keys, just ``sum(items.values())`` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method if you wish to keep the loop for displaying the items as well. Here, you can use a variable to keep track of the total and `item_total += inven_count` is shorthand for `item_total = item_total + inven_count`

```
import pprint 
items = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12} 

print('Inventory:')

item_total = 0

for item, inven_count in items.items():
    item_total += inven_count
    print(str(inven_count) + ' ' + item)

print('Total number of items: ' + str(item_total))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't care about the keys in the dictionary, just the values so you can use `items.values()`. You want the sum so use the built in function `sum()`.

Putting that all together gives:

```py
item_total = sum(items.values())
```

No for loop required!